# how to skip one item to display from database while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_main_menu ORDER BY fld_main_menu_id ASC");
    while($menu_list = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  ?>  
  <li>
    <a href="content_editor.php?main_menu_id=<?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_id']; ?>&menu_name=<?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_name'];?>">
      <?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_name']; ?><span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>
  </li>     
  <?php } ?>    
</ul>
```

Here display menu from database:

1. Home
2. About
3. Board of directors
4. Management
5. Products
6. Claim
7. Career

But **I don't want to display Board of directors from database and I want put a static page link here**. Now what I have to do?

Comment: you can use `where` clause in your sql query. `select * from tbl_main_menu WHERE fld_main_menu_name != 'Board of directors' order by fld_main_menu_id asc`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this from html

```
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <?php 
          $sql = mysql_query("select * from tbl_main_menu order by fld_main_menu_id asc");
          while($menu_list = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       ?>  

          <?php if ($menu_list['fld_main_menu_name']!='Board of directors') { // check if name is Board of directors ?>
          <li>
          <a href="content_editor.php?main_menu_id=<?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_id']; ?>&menu_name=<?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_name'];?>">
             <?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_name']; ?><span class="arrow"></span>
          </a>
          </li>           
        <?php } //end of if 
          } //end of while ?>      
    </ul>
```

And you can do it like this from database:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from tbl_main_menu where fild_main_menu_name != 'Board of directors' order by fld_main_menu_id asc");
```

Comment: It will generate invalid HTML code.  An opening `<li>` will be created for ever result but it will be missing a closing `</li>` tag for 'Board of directors'.  You'll end up with a lingering `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some `if` statements in your PHP, but while your MySQL is right there why not modify that like this:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <!-- This is a static page -->
    <li><a href="static_page.html">Static Page</a></li>    
    <?php 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_main_menu WERE fld_main_menu_name != 'Board of directors' ORDER BY fld_main_menu_id asc");
        while($menu_list = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>  
    <li>
        <a href="content_editor.php?main_menu_id=<?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_id']; ?>&menu_name=<?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_name'];?>">
         <?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_name']; ?><span class="arrow"></span>
         </a>
    </li>           


    <?php } ?>

    <!-- This is a static page -->
    <li><a href="static_page.html">Static Page</a></li>    
</ul>
```

In either method you'll need to make sure the spelling and case of the link name is exact.

Also note I included static links at the beginning and end for you as an example.

**Edit:** Here's how I would do it based on the comments below:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">   
    <?php 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_main_menu ORDER BY fld_main_menu_id asc");
        while($menu_list = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>
    <?php if('fld_main_menu_name' != 'board of directors'){?>
    <li>
        <a href="content_editor.php?main_menu_id=<?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_id']; ?>&menu_name=<?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_name'];?>">
         <?php echo $menu_list['fld_main_menu_name']; ?><span class="arrow"></span>
         </a>
    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="custom_page_path.php">Custom page name<span class="arrow"></span></a>
    </li>

    <?php } //end for if...else ?> 
    <?php } //end for while loop ?> 
</ul>
```

Comment: But I want static page link same position of Board of directors

Comment: In that case I'd use a conditional statement like the answer provided by Randyka Yudhistira.  I'll modify mine like I would do it.

Comment: Does not working Ding and  Randyka Yudhistira provided solution. why?

Comment: You need to tweak them according to your setup.  The case might not be right where we have *board of directors* and you may need to change that to be exactly what is in the db.  Are you getting any errors?